# Strings turn out blank when split

Tags: java, string, parsing, split

```
String data = line.split(":")[1];

String location = data.split("|")[0];
String type = data.split("|")[1];

System.out.println("D: " + type);
int x = Integer.parseInt(location.split("-")[0]);
int y = Integer.parseInt(location.split("-")[1]);

int t = Integer.parseInt(type);
```

The original strings that are inputed into this parser are formated like "DATA:3,3|1". I'm trying to parse it to the format of "DATA:`x`,`y`|`t`". The problem is that the string `location` is blank when it's split off from the string `data`. Why?

Answer (score 8):

Because `split()` takes a regex as parameter, and `|` is actually a regex special char (and also a syntaxically valid regex as is, which explains that no error is thrown).

You need to escape it: either `split("\\|")`, or `split("[|]")`.

Answer (score 0):

As sp00m said you can use :

> `split("\\|")` **or** `split("[|]")`

Or you can use

```
split(Pattern.quote("|"));
```

To test beforehand if the string contains a character, just use

> String#contains()

```
if (string.contains("\\|")) { 
    // Split it. 
} 
else {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("String " + string + " does not contain |"); 
 }
```